# Can you use Github Pages for Minecraft Server Domains?

Tags: github, server

Now, I am not saying to host the minecraft server on github pages. I am wondering if you can use just the domain name that github pages provides you with, and use that domain name for a minecraft server hosted on my local machine?

Would this be possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, it won’t be. The github page domain can be only used on github pages. It doesn’t provide a CNAME or A record configuration for us.
However, it is possible for you to register the github student pack and sign up for a free domain or a freenom domain.
And, sign an A or a CNAME record to your local machine.

Comment: I would upvote, but I don't have enough reputation to do that. Thanks for the answer.